# Only Text with sansserif

Tags: fonts, xetex, polyglossia, sans-serif

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis and want to display my whole documents in a font without serif. 
My header file looks like this

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,            % Papierformat
    oneside,            % einseitiger Druck
    %twoside,           % zweiseitiger Druck
    12pt,               % Schriftgröße
    onecolumn,          % einspaltiger Text
    %twocolumn,         % zweispaltiger Text
    openright,          % Kapitel dürfen nur auf einer rechten Seite beginnen
    openany,            % Kapitel dürfen rechts oder links beginnen
    parskip=half,       % eine halbe Zeile Abstand zw. Absätzen
    headsepline,        % Kopfzeilenlinie
    footsepline,        % Fußzeilenlinie
    bibliography=totoc, % Bibliographie im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    %idxtotoc           % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    ]{scrbook}
\linespread{1.25}
\recalctypearea %Neuberechnung des Satzspiegels

\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{german}
\else
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\fi


\usepackage[
    left=25mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=30mm,
    bottom=40mm,
    %includeheadfoot,
    ]{geometry}

% deutsche Silbentrennung etc.

% Grafiken: PDF, GIF, PNG
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Farben
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{LinkColor}{rgb}{0,0,0.6}
\definecolor{ListingBG}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}


% Hyperlinks (anklickbar im PDF)
\usepackage[%
    pdftitle={Programmierung einer Client-Server-Applikation 
        zur Realisierung eines Restful-Web-Services},%
    pdfauthor={Vorname Nachname},%
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines
]{hyperref}   

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,%    farbige Links statt Rahmen
    linkcolor=LinkColor,
    citecolor=LinkColor,
    filecolor=LinkColor,
    menucolor=LinkColor,
    urlcolor=LinkColor,
    }
%Schriftart für Quellcode definieren    


\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0}


% erweiterte Tabellen
\usepackage{array}

% Formelsatz
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Definition eigener Operatoren (im Header)
\DeclareMathOperator{\rg}{Rang}  

% Fortlaufende Kapitelüberschriften in der Kopfzeile
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}} 
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{\pagemark}

% Stil des Literaturverzeichnis
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\makeatletter  %Ändert den Abstand der Nummer zum Text im Abbildungsverzeichnis
\def\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4em}}
\makeatother




\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,format=plain,labelsep=endash}


\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{titling} % um /thetitle, /thedate aufrufen zu können


\usepackage{url} 
\urlstyle{same} %gleicht die Schrift der URL im Quellenverzeichnis an 
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\normalsize}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{-\topskip}}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{%
  \vspace*{1\baselineskip plus .1\baselineskip minus .167\baselineskip}}
```

My main file looks like this

```
\input{header}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4em}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\psset{framesep =2pt, arrows =->, arrowinset= 0.12, arrowsize = 6pt, linejoin=1, shortput=nab, npos=0.4}

\let\oldsection\section
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\let\oldchapter\chapter

\renewcommand{\section}{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}\oldsection}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{subsection}\oldsubsection}
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{chapter}\oldchapter}
\frontmatter





\include{kapitel/titelseite_Standard}

\include{kapitel/erklaerung}


\tableofcontents




\input{kapitel/abkuerz}




\mainmatter

\input{kapitel/Einleitung}
\input{kapitel/Problemstellung}
\input{kapitel/Programmierumgebungen}
\input{kapitel/Grundlagen}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\input{kapitel/Implementierung}
\input{kapitel/Analyse}
\input{kapitel/Fazit}
\input{kapitel/Ausblick}


\printglossary[title= Glossar]

\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings

\bibliography{biblio/biblio}

%\appendix
%\include{anhang/ersteranhang}

\end{document}
```

I thought that I can change the font of the whole document with

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

but only the headings changed, you can see it clearly in the picture.[image]

Thank you for your help. I don't know how to provide a working minimal example because my problems dependts on this settings. I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you tried `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}}` (to be placed in the preamble)?

Comment: Just tried it after your answer. Didn't work for me...

Comment: Please also tell us what's in the file `header.tex`.

Comment: It's published above :)

Comment: Do you want to use sans serif fonts or you are forced to? I am asking, because such a thesis will look extremally ugly.

Comment: It's a personal choice from my professor. I also think that it looks nicer with serif fonts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}`.

In fact, the problem is only when compiling with `xetex`. It is caused by polyglossia, which instructs LaTeX to use, say when switching to German language, the `\rmfamilylatin` macro which is given the `\rmfamily` meaning which per definition uses `\rmdefault`.

Hence another approach is to do `\let\rmfamilylatin\sffamily` near end of preamble. But one then *also* needs `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` for page headers it appears.

Comment: Works fine, would you mind sharing your knowledge about this problem?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem with the preamble you provide. Thus, I figured some unknown source was causing a short-circuit of `\familydefault` in favour of `\rmdefault`. A wild guess, nothing more. Again I can't reproduce hence debug your problem with the information given.

Comment: ah wait, yes I can reproduce with `xetex`. Hence polyglossia is culprit. Will provide details later.

Comment: Yes I too needed a lot of time to get started with xetex... Thank you!